# Can I work on external hard disk until I have recovered all the deleted files from computer

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a Dell laptop that have a single partition named "C drive" and I lost my  whole data during reinstalling OS and I want to recover my whole data but I need some days to recover my data, So my concern is that can I do copy, paste and delete operation on my external hard disk. Because many people warns me that "Do not use the laptop you want to recover files from until you have recovered all the files you want."

Additionally, I have questions to ask, Does the deleted data of the external hard disk go to that disk that running OS.

OR

Does it effect on data recovery.

Thanks Vipin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During normal operations MS Windows create and remove a lot of files in temporary directory, use swap. And those operations can overwrite the files which you want to recover, located on your C filesystem . So, **no**, do not use your computer on this way.

Comment: Thanks @Romeo, I have one more question. If I deleted some files from external hard disk and I want to recover that files from computer but that external hard disk is no more, So any possibilities can I recover deleted files without using external hard disk.

Comment: @Yajuvendra, no, software for undelete check the content of filesystem blocks. So if you do not have the disk you can't restore those files

Comment: @Yajuvendra, the safe bet would be to remove the drive and stick in an enclosure or use a USB adapter to connect it for cleanup/recovery.  You can boot from a Linux DVD or USB live session if you don't have another way to boot Windows on that computer, or connect the drive to another computer, and clean up the drive from there.